# visual studio c++ 2010 redefine a windows api function

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

We have code that first gets implemented and tested on windows. But eventually the code will be compiled for Integrity OS. Most Operating system specific functions like the creation of semaphores do not compile correctly in Windows. Rather than using macros to have Operating system specific code, I just want visual studio to ignore those functions.

So can I change the project settings to tell visual to comment out certain functions?

For instance I want to tell visual studio to comment out any instances of a function such as CreateSemaphore. I got half way there. I went to project settings and told visual to undefine CreateSemaphore. Then I put #define CreateSemaphore // on top of a header file that uses that function and that works fine. But I want to do this project wide, so I tried messing with preprocessor defines but I am not sure of the syntax for this.

Is it possible to do what I want and what is the right project properties I need to change?